# How to overwrite read-only files in kubernetes/minikube

Tags: java, linux, kubernetes, devops, minikube

I have been trying to overwrite my java certs but i keep getting stuck. Here is a copy of my yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: api-gateway
    labels:
        app: api-gateway
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: api-gateway
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: api-gateway
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: api-gateway
            image: api-gateway
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
              keytool -list -keystore /usr/java/openjdk-18/lib/security/cacerts  -alias local
     
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/java/openjdk-18/lib/security
              name: cacerts
          initContainers:
          - name: init-cacerts
            image: api-gateway
            imagePullPolicy: Never
            command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
              cp -R /usr/java/openjdk-18/lib/security/* /cacerts/
              keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias local -file /security/tls.crt -keystore /cacerts/cacerts -storepass changeit
               keytool -list -keystore /cacerts/cacerts -alias local
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /cacerts
              name: cacerts
            - mountPath: /security
              name: tls
          volumes:
          - name: cacerts
            emptyDir: {}
          - name: tls
            secret:
              secretName: keycloak-tls
```

The thing is that, in my init-container it works just fine but when i import it into my container the data is incomplete, what i added is not there.. Any help please

Comment: The yaml definition is fine.  Please check the path in init container the truststore or certs  is updated to /cacerts/cacerts. In main container it’s referred only to cacerts.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I know the error is coming from my main container but I just don't seem to understand it. Can you please help

Comment: I mean the path given in keytool list of main container is just referring /cacerts not /cacerts/cacerts file.  In init container the certs are imported to /cacerts/cacerts file.  So if I am not wrong in main container it should be keytool -list -keystore /usr/java/openjdk-18/lib/security/cacerts/cacerts -alias local

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I am getting an error keystore file does not exist : /usr/java/open-jdk/lib/security/cacerts/cacerts

Comment: Also as the images used in init and main container are same.  if objective is only to load certs from secret then it can be done in main container directly no need of init container  also no need to write it to emptydir{} / scratch volume.  Secret can be loaded into main container and as part of entryscript the cert can be loaded into truststore.  Ignore this message if there is different objective for init container.

Comment: Ensure mountPath is also reflecting the same

Comment: Yes the thing is the file is read-only so I have to overwrite at start up. That is where the issue is... @NatarajMedayhal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246717/discussion-between-ferrocene-and-nataraj-medayhal).

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I think I found something.. I change the directory and I cat the imported file but it missing the updated certificate.. I mean the certificate leaving the init container is not the same as the one entering the main container. What could have caused that